# Unix sed command to replace brackets in file

Tags: sed

I need to replace `"..."` with `<...>` in a file. I have used this command `sed '/^#include/s/"/</g' file.c` found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30312436/how-to-replace-angle-brackets-with-quotation-marks), but the output is incorrect. How can I fix this?

Input:

```
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "graph.h"
```

Output:

```
#include <stdlib.h<
#include <graph.h<
```

Expected output:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <graph.h>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The issue with the command is the `g` at the end. It will cause *all* double quotes to be substituted with `<` on each line matching `^#include`.  Notice how the StackOverflow question that you link to is concerned with replacing the `<>` with `""` (which could be done using `y/<>/""/`, or less efficiently using `s/[<>]/"/g`, on the relevant lines), not the other way around like you want.

If you had used first `s/"/</` (no `g`) followed by `s/"/>` (no `g` here either), you would have been ok:

```bsh
sed '/^#include/ { s/"/</; s/"/>/; }' file.c >file-new.c
```

The first substitution replaces the first double quote and the second substitution replaces the first one in the now modified string.

To correct the file (assuming you did an in-place edit), just replace the `<` at the end of the line with `>`:

```bsh
sed '/^#include/ s/<$/>/' file.c >file-new.c
```

This matches `<$` (an `<` at the end of the line), and replaces it with `>`.

Look at the resulting `file-new.c` and then replace `file.c` with it if it looks ok.

Answer (score 10):

You need to replace two equal characters `"` for two *distinct* characters `<` and `>`. Your command doesn't work because it replaces all occurrences of one character `"` for *one* character only `<`. So try this:

```bsh
# capture the final word between double quotes
# and replace it for itself enclosed in brackets
$ sed '/^#include/s/"\([^"]*\)"/<\1>/' file
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <graph.h>
```